# why can't return assignment statement

Tags: python

In IDLE,
I write a function and intend to return a value. but it can't return

```
>>> def grade(value):
    if value > 100:
        return (value=100)
    if value <0:
        return (value=0)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

why can't return? but when I change to

```
value = 100
return value
```

It can work

Comment: just write `return 100` and `return 0`. you cannot have assignments **(=)** in `return` statements. Also be careful of your indentation

Comment: It doesn't really make any sense to return an assignment, that's why. When you return the function is over, so there's really no point in assigning to anything as it will never be available.

Comment: Because allowing assignment statements to be used as an expression leads to pernicious bugs. Compare `return value == 1` versus `return value = 1`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not that I am advocating for this in any way, but there is one scenario that the assignment would have an effect: if you wish to both return a value and set a global variable to that value.

Answer (score 7):

In a [return statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement), only an expression can come after the "return".

> `return_stmt ::=  "return" [expression_list]`

An assignment is a [statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). You can't put a statement after "return", because a statement isn't an expression.

Consider skipping the assignment entirely. Just `return` will suffice:

```
return 100
```